# Null is not an object (evaluating 'e.length')

Tags: jquery, wordpress, typeerror

So I am getting this error on my wordpress site and can't work out what's causing it. I have attached a screenshot of what shows up when the error is expanded though my gut feeling is that it's got something to do with how the jQuery is loaded.

If anyone can give me any pointers or things to check - that'd be great.
[image]

Code in script.js:17

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // set the container that Masonry will be inside of in a var
    var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');

    // create empty var msnry
    var msnry;

    // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
    imagesLoaded( container, function() {
        msnry = new Masonry( container, {
            itemSelector: '.masonry-item'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Show me what scripts.js looks like around line 17

Comment: @Quantastical it's part of a masonry document. Code added to question

Comment: What is the `container` variable?

Comment: I've just updated showing the whole function which defines the variable.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is an element on the page with `id="masonry"`? Did you try using jQuery's selector `$('#masonry');` instead of going plain-ol JavaScript?

Comment: Hmm...there's no element with `id="masonry"` so that might be causing it. I've unloaded masonry calls in the page to see if it prevents the error.

Comment: If there is no element with ID masonry then, yes, that is very likely the issue. Since the querySelector doesn't find anything, it returns `null`. `null` does not have a `length` property and will trigger this error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104579/discussion-between-dwinnbrown-and-quantastical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs on line 17 of `scripts.js`.

There is something wrong with that line that is causing the `Masonry` plugin to try reading the `length` property on an object that is `null`.

`document.querySelector()` will return `null` when it doesn't find a match, so the problem is that it is looking for an element with id "masonry" that doesn't exist.

You should figure out why there isn't an element with id "masonry" and correct that behavior. Perhaps look at a sample of the theme you are using and compare to see where `#masonry` needs to be.